# Add dynamic value to the custom attribute for radiobuttonList in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a custom attribute(Ex: Custom-value in code) for radiobuttionlist and i could add value from database. Based on that custom attribute value my logic would be work.
In aspx page:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblQU" 
    runat="server" 
    Custom-value='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsEditable"))==true ?true:false %>' 
    AutoPostBack="True" 
    RepeatDirection="Vertical"  
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblQuickUpdate_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Code behind code:

```
List<ProxyStub> lstFields = SvcClient.UMFields(result);
if (lstFields != null)
{
   rblQU.DataSource = lstUpdateFields;
   rblQU.DataTextField = "ShowText";
   rblQU.DataValueField = "UpdateFieldsID";
   rblQuickUpdate.DataBind();
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: How it is not working?

Comment: Custom-value is not binding to from database

Comment: Did you check the HTML? Because the RadioButtonList table with the attribute will only show up if it actually has any ListItems.